# Moment of inertia of tetratomic molecule

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, moment-of-inertia

I am reading Landau's [Mechanics](https://archive.org/details/Mechanics3eLandauLifshitz/page/n125/mode/2up). About the problem 1(c) on page 101, Ch.32, with all masses equal and the molecule being a regular tetrahedron, the solution gives that all principal moments of inertia should be equal. I understand that I can take the first principal axis of inertia on the symmetry axis of the regular tetrahedron but I just don't see what are the orientations of the second and the third principal axes of inertia. Or put it another way, can the conclusion of 3 equal principal moments of inertia be deduced from the symmetry of the regular tetrahedron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, if you know of multiple axes which can serve as principal axes, and all of these axes have the same principal moment, then any vector that lies in the [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of these axes will also be a principal axis. In this case, we know of three axes (four, in fact) that can serve as principal axes:  the axes connecting the central atom to each of the "satellite" atoms.  These vectors span all of 3-D space, and so any vector can serve as a principal axis, meaning that the inertia tensor is just a multiple of the identity.

---

**Proof:** Let $\hat{e}_A$, $\hat{e}_B$, and $\hat{e}_C$ be three vectors that each connect the central atom to different "satellite" atoms.  For concreteness, let $\hat{e}_A = \hat{z}$ point "up", along what you describe as the symmetry axis of the tetrahedron.  You (correctly) note that $\hat{e}_A$ must be a principal axis of the tetrahedron, i.e., $\mathbf{I} \hat{e}_A = \lambda \hat{e}_A$ for some $\lambda$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the inertia tensor.  By symmetry, we must also have $\mathbf{I} \hat{e}_B = \lambda \hat{e}_B$ and $\mathbf{I} \hat{e}_C = \lambda \hat{e}_C$, since all of these axes are equivalent.

Now, the space of vectors $\hat{e}_A$, $\hat{e}_B$, and $\hat{e}_C$ spans 3-D space, so we apply the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to get an *orthonormal* set of vectors $\{\hat{e}_A, \hat{e}_2, \hat{e}_3 \}$, where $\hat{e}_2$ and $\hat{e}_3$ are linear combinations of the original vectors, e.g.,
$$
\hat{e}_2 = c_A \hat{e}_A + c_B \hat{e}_B + c_C \hat{e}_C
$$
and similarly for $\hat{e}_3$.
But by the properties of the inertia tensor, $\hat{e}_2$ is also an eigenvector of $\mathbf{I}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$:
$$
\mathbf{I} \hat{e}_2 = \mathbf{I} \left( c_A \hat{e}_A + c_B \hat{e}_B + c_C \hat{e}_C \right) = c_A \mathbf{I} \hat{e}_A + c_B \mathbf{I} \hat{e}_B + c_C \mathbf{I} \hat{e}_C \\= \lambda \left( c_A \hat{e}_A + c_B \hat{e}_B + c_C \hat{e}_C \right) = \lambda \hat{e}_2.
$$
Similarly, $\hat{e}_3$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{I}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  We can thus conclude that $\{\hat{e}_A, \hat{e}_2, \hat{e}_3 \}$ is a set of three orthogonal vectors, all of which have eigenvalue $\lambda$, and so $\mathbf{I} = \lambda \mathbf{1}$.

Comment: As an aside, this argument also implies that a molecule like $\mathrm{CH}_3 \mathrm{Cl}$, with one odd "satellite" atom, will also still have an inertia tensor that is proportional to the identity.

Comment: "As a general rule, if you know of multiple axes which can serve as principal axes, then any vector that lies in the linear span of these axes will also be a principal axis." This is probably true only if the components of the tensor of inertia with respect to these axes are equal?

Comment: @Michael Does it? In CH3Cl it's clear that the C-Cl vector must be a principal axis, but how do you deduce that the C-H vectors are? Thinking of it in terms of mass distribution, the molecule is much closer to a 'dumbbell' (two big atoms bonded to each other) than to anything else -- compared to the chlorine, the hydrogens are almost rounding errors.

Comment: Also, if the goal is showing $\mathbf I = \lambda \mathbf 1$, then Gram-Schmidt is redundant. Using the same calculation one can show $\mathbf I \hat e = \lambda \hat e$ for any $\hat e$, and you're done.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Yeah, I thought it over further while walking to work and you're right.  I was thinking of the three equivalent linearly independent axes connecting the molecular COM to the hydrogens.  The problem is that we don't have sufficient symmetry any more to argue that these three axes are principal axes, and so the argument can't proceed past that point.  (And [Wikipedia notes that chloromethane is a symmetric top, not a spherical top.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy#Classification_of_molecular_rotors))

Comment: @akhmeteli:  Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you can choose one axis based on the symmetry (passing through one vertex and the center of the opposite base of the tetrahedron. You can choose the second axis based on the symmetry to pass through the center of mass of the tetrahedron and to intersect one of the edges. The third axis is chosen to pass through the center of mass and to be orthogonal to the other two axis.

So there are different ways of choosing the principal axes of a tetrahedron, not just some unique set of principal axes.

Comment: But can the conclusion of 3 equal principal moments of inertia be instantly deduced from the symmetry of the regular tetrahedron?

Comment: @rioiong : I am afraid I don't understand your question. I explained how one can choose the principal axes based on the symmetry. Are you asking how to calculate the moments of inertia with respect to these axes?

Comment: I think @Michael Seifert 's answer serves a good explanation to my question.